# Background image gets choppy through different elements

Tags: html, css

I need a bit of help with my background image.  The issue is that it appears to "reset" (not really sure how to describe it) with each element in my HTML code, so the page looks very choppy.  Is there anyway to smooth it out?  I have tried this in both Chrome and Firefox and get the same result.  The background is on my About Me page, below is a link to it.  Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[First Project](https://github.com/lkovach/first_project)

Comment: It's considered good practice at SO to present a sample code lines themselves, although the link showing it may be present. To provide for the possibility that the link may not exist tomorrow and the queston may be still relevant to another visitor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to anyone that may have read this already, but I finally found the answer to my question here: [W3 Schools Backgrounds](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp)

Hopefully this will help anyone else that might be having issues with their background.